# What installs will only be installed inside an activated Virtual environment?

Tags: virtualenv, zurb-foundation-6

If a virtual environment (virtualenv) is activate will all software installed in it like Zurb Foundation will only be installed inside that virtual environment?

Comment: Does that answer your question? The short answer is only Python packages installed with pip when your virtualenv is active.

Comment: yup good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a [Django Zurb Foundation package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-zurb-foundation) on PyPI so that package can be installed in a virtualenv. Not all software installed when a virtualenv is active will be contained inside that environment. Only Python packages installed with pip.